# How do I set as startDate the first day of previous month with Datepicker jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jquery datepicker to show a calendar with enabled days only from the first of the previous month and then.I want to set as startDate the first of the previous month with Datepicker jquery. This is the function i use to find the first day of the previous month

```
function firstOfLastMonth() {
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() -1);
return '01/' + month + '/' + year;      
}
```

and this is for the datepicker

```
$('.datech').datepicker({
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
startDate: firstOfLastMonth,
language: "en"
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be 'minDate' instead of 'startDate' assuming you are using the jquery UI datepicker ([docs](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max))? If you want to set the initial value, simply add it to the input field (`<input type="text" class="datech" value="01/01/2018" />` or set the value using the jquery `val()` method `$('.datech').val(firstOfLastMonth())`

Comment: it worked with this fine

var year = now.getFullYear();
var month = now.getMonth() - 1;
...
startDate: new Date(year, month, 1),

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
return '01/' + month + '/' + year;
```

to

```
return year + '-' + month + '-' + '01';
```